# Add O and OU parts in DN of a standalone CA in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I have a standalone CA managed in Windows Server 2012 R2. Its certificate has a `DN` that includes `CN` and `DC`, as in `CN=CAName,DC=domain,DC=tld`. This root certificate cannot be stored in firefox, probably because it lacks `O` and/or `OU` parts, so I would like to change the root certificate, adding `O=companyname,OU=IT` to the `DN`.

I noticed that issued certificates have "X509v3 Authority Key Identifier" specifying the `keyid` (they lack `dirname`, `serial`, or any other reference to the CA key). I think this means that I may issue a new certificate, using the same private CA key, without invalidate all issued certificates.

So, how may I create a new CA certificate that includes `O` and `OU` in its `DN`?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you merely guessing that the problem with the current cert is that it lists a CN entry in the distinguished name, or have you found some article explaining that problem? It's possible that what you're trying to do won't fix your trouble at all. It may be that the O field is required but I'm not seeing anything suggesting OU can't be omitted. And CN certainly seems valid.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I am quite confident this is the problem. As a proof, when I add the certificate in firefox trusted keystore, the browser accept it, but it is not listed. No errors. It just disappear. I noticed firefox use the O field for sorting the certificates. This might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this means that I may issue a new certificate, using the same private CA key, without invalidate all issued certificates.

unfortunately, you can't. You will have to build a new CA nd PKI tree and decommission current one when all issued certificates are migrated. There are no other workarounds.

> or any other reference to the CA key

they reference issuer name in `Issuer` field. So if you change CA name, new CA certificate with different `Subject` field cannot be used to validate previously issued certificates even if both CA certificates share the same key pair. It is how certificate chaining engine works when binding certificates in chain.